# Is there a rails gem for products and shopping cart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart

I've found some gems like spree commerce but that's too complex for what I need.

I only need system of products and a shopping cart (without payments) to implement within current rails app. Is there any gem that does this?

Comment: You can check http://tryshoppe.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [gem](https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart) quite handy. The syntax is pretty expressive like

```
@cart.add(@product, @product.price) #for adding an item
@cart.clear  #clears cart
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/e_commerce to see a list of popular e_commerces.

Personally I have experience with https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce and I recommend you to try.

Cheers,
Bojan

Answer (score 1):

I use [AWESOME RUBY](http://awesome-ruby.com/) to look for useful gems.